# Hard disk capacity discrepancy between enclosures

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I recently bought a 3 terabyte internal hard drive to replace a 2TB drive I
filled. Using the same [enclosure](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182155) that's been housing my 2TB drive, Ubuntu
reports the capacity of the new drive as 802 gigabytes.

I also have a multi-purpose [SATA-to-USB-and-power adapter](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812329640). When the new
drive is connected using that device, Ubuntu reports the full 3 terabytes.

I'm seeing the same behavior whether I use gpt or msdos partition tables.

This seems like a limitation of the enclosure, but I can't explain why it
recognizes the complete 2TB of one drive but only 800 gigabytes of a larger
drive.

Can this be explained by the capabilities of the hard disk enclosure? Can I
verify that by inspecting the system state? Is there some feature I need to
search for when buying a new enclosure?

When the disk is mounted through the **USB dongle**, Ubuntu's "Disks" utility
reports the following:

> - Model: ST3000DM 008-2DM166 (0006)
> - 3.0 TB (3,000,592,982,016 bytes)
> - Serial number: 20140404

But when mounted through the **enclosure**:

> - Model: ST3000DM 008-2DM166 (0103)
> - Size: 802 GB (801,569,726,464 bytes)
> - Serial number: ST3000DM00_Z505FLQF

Comment: Is drive partitioned as gpt, some have proprietary MBR partitioning for backwards compatibility. Then drive is not fully see as partitioning is not the correct gpt type. Also in past many older USB converters & encloses did not work with larger drives or gpt drives. So I would expect if issue then it is enclosure. From Ubuntu post this on 3TB drive: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdX` where sdX is 3TB drive, sdb, sdc or whatever.

Comment: This is normal because if it only support 2TB, it truncates LBA address to 32-bit(Max size 2^32*512), so 800 GB is the lowest 32bit your 3TB drive reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for data from the manufacturer. Pending on what hardware / firmware is build into your enclosure it might just be old or that might just be the part that they saved money on.

It is not uncommon to get stuck at the 2 TB barrier.

So if you are lucky you can get a firmware update for the enclosure or it might just be that a different driver (I doubt it) exists.

In terms of "quick driver check" you might get yourself a knoppix and boot from that CD (www.knoppix.org) that is the best I have seen in terms of hardware recognition.

If knoppix sees the drive in the enclosure correctly that ther is a way your ubuntu can do that as well.

Comment: You're correct. I should have read the product page more closely: it's mentioned by verified owners *and* the technical specifications. So, time for a new enclosure. Thanks!